# How to find latest record from two different tables

Tags: mysql, analytics

There are 2 tables table1 and table 2

[image: table1 data]

[image: table2 data]

First column, **foreign_id** is the common column between both tables.
Data type of all the related columns are same.

---

Now, we need to find the latest record based on timestamp column, for each foreign_id taking from both the tables, for example as below, also an extra column **from_table**, which shows from which table this row is selected.
[image: result table]

One method that I can think of is

> Combine both the tables 
>   then, find the latest for each foreign_id column

Any, better way to do this as there could be 5000+  rows in both the tables.

Comment: Does each foreign_id appear more than once in each table?

Comment: @ysth yes, the table can contain multiple rows for each foreign_id

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  t1.foreign_id,
  MAX(t1.timestamp) max_time_table1,
  MAX(t2.timestamp) max_time_table2
FROM *table1* t1
LEFT JOIN *table2* t2 USING (foreign_id)
GROUP BY foreign_id;
```

Note: This can be a bit slow, if the number of records are quite large.

However you can also use this:

```
SELECT a.foreign_id, 
IF(a.max_time_table1 > a.max_time_table2, a.max_time_table1, a.max_time_table2) latest_update
FROM(  
 SELECT
 t1.foreign_id,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t1.timestamp ORDER BY t1.id DESC),',',1)    max_time_table1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.timestamp ORDER BY t2.id DESC),',',1) max_time_table2
FROM *table1* t1
LEFT JOIN *table2* t2 USING (foreign_id)
GROUP BY foreign_id) a;
```

Make sure the id columns in both tables are auto_increment.

Comment: According to the first answer, we will get 2 columns with named **max_time_table1** and **max_time_table2**
And whenever there is a match According to join condition then there will be value in both the columns.
But result I need is that for each foreign id get 1 row, and that row could be from table1 or table2 based on condition whose timestamp is latest

Comment: See the last query @abhi

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, this would do then:

```
 SELECT 
  foreign_id,
  CASE
   WHEN max_time_table1 < max_time_table2 THEN max_time_table2
   WHEN max_time_table2 < max_time_table1 THEN max_time_table1
 END as timestamps
FROM(
 SELECT
  t1.foreign_id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t1.timestamp ORDER BY t1.id DESC),',',1)    max_time_table1,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.timestamp ORDER BY t2.id DESC),',',1) max_time_table2
FROM *table1* t1
LEFT JOIN *table2* t2 USING (foreign_id)
GROUP BY foreign_id) a;
```